# VNC server on Ubuntu 22.04 only show blank screen

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, ubuntu-22.04

On Ubuntu one can enable a VNC server via Settings > Sharing > screen-sharing > VNC (my Desktop is german, I just guessed).

Another way is to start a vnc-server via shell, i.e.:

```
x0tigervncserver -display :0 -passwordfile ~/.secret/pass -FrameRate 10 -ZlibLevel 9 -rfbport 5900 -localhost=0
```

However, either way, connecting from another machine only shows a black/blank screen. I can test it i.e. like this locally (I also tried other vnc-viewers)

```
xtigervncviewer  192.168.1.125
```

*Now I have found a way to do make VNC work on Ubuntu 22.04 by disabling wayland by editing the gdm3-setup: `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. Setting the relevant line to `WaylandEnable=false` and restarting the session via `systemctl restart gdm3`. From then on the above commands do show the remote window instead of a blank screen.*

**the question**:
Has anyone found a way to actually use the screen-sharing solution on Ubuntu with wayland?

These are the requirements for my setup:

- Share the actual screen as I do not want another session opened. I just want to see my living-room pc from everywhere I go.
- tunneling it all through SSH must be possible
- ideally resizing of the client window would be nice

Comment: mostly I remember that it refers about the sessions. on xrdp you needed to fix to not get the blank screen. If I remember correctly I think that might be the same